# VHDL: Case Statement choices must cover all possible values of expression

Tags: vhdl

I'm working on project which should convert data from analog to digital with approximation and I have error when i try compile code in Quartus II 9.1sp2 Web Edition which is shown in title with Case Statement in the code below:

```
architecture behavior of adc is
type state is (reset, state1, state2, state3, state4, state5, state6, state7, state8, state9, state10);
signal nx_state : state;

begin
    process (in_clk, rst_n, start)
begin
    if(rst_n'event and rst_n='0') then
        B_hold <= "1111";
        D_out <= "0000";
        data_out <= "0000";
        hold <= '1';
        sample <= '0';
        eoc <= '0';
        
        if start = '1' then
            nx_state <= state1;
        else
            nx_state <= reset;
        end if;

    elsif(in_clk'event and in_clk='1') then
        case nx_state is
            when state1 => nx_state <= state2;
                B_hold <= "0000";
                hold <= '0';
                sample <= '1';
            
            when state2 => nx_state <= state3;
                B_hold <= "1111";
                D_out <= "0000";
            
            when state3 => nx_state <= state4;
                B_hold(3) <= '0';
                D_out(3) <= '1';
                data_out(3) <= '1';
            
            when state4 => nx_state <= state5;
                if comp_in = '1' then
                    B_hold(3) <= '0';
                    D_out(3) <= '1';
                    data_out(3) <= '1';
                else
                    B_hold(3) <= '1';
                    D_out(3) <= '0';
                    data_out(3) <= '0';
                end if;
            
            when state5 => nx_state <= state6;
                B_hold(2) <= '0';
                D_out(2) <= '1';
                data_out(2) <= '1';
            
            when state6 => nx_state <= state7;
                if comp_in = '1' then
                    B_hold(2) <= '0';
                    D_out(2) <= '1';
                    data_out(2) <= '1';
                else
                    B_hold(2) <= '1';
                    D_out(2) <= '0';
                    data_out(2) <= '0';
                end if;
            
            when state7 => nx_state <= state8;
                B_hold(1) <= '0';
                D_out(1) <= '1';
                data_out(1) <= '1';
            
            when state8 => nx_state <= state9; 
                if comp_in = '1' then
                    B_hold(1) <= '0';
                    D_out(1) <= '1';
                    data_out(1) <= '1';
                else
                    B_hold(1) <= '1';
                    D_out(1) <= '0';
                    data_out(1) <= '0';
                end if;
                
            when state9 => nx_state <= state10; 
                B_hold(0) <= '0';
                D_out(0) <= '1';
                data_out(0) <= '1';
            
            when state10 => nx_state <= reset;
                if comp_in = '1' then
                    B_hold(0) <= '0';
                    D_out(0) <= '1';
                    data_out(0) <= '1';
                else
                    B_hold(0) <= '1';
                    D_out(0) <= '0';
                    data_out(0) <= '0';
                end if;
                eoc <= '1';
        end case;
    end if;
end process;
end behavior;
```

I'm new newbie at vhdl and I don't know what exactly is wrong with the conditions shown above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reset is level sensitive.  So change

```
if(rst_n'event and rst_n='0') then
```

to

```
if(rst_n='0') then
```

It is also unusual to have a condition within the reset condition

```
    if start = '1' then
        nx_state <= state1;
    else
        nx_state <= reset;
    end if;
```

Hence, you probably just want:

```
    nx_state <= reset;
```

Comment: Thank you, everything works and I also add `when others` at the end of case

Answer (score 3):

Your type includes a state named reset. You need a when for that state.

```
case nx_state is
    when reset =>
```